# Javascript while not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm trying to create calendar and I tried below.

```
function displayCalendar() {

    var dateNow = new Date();
    var month = dateNow.getMonth();

     var counter = 1;

     var nextMonth = month + 1;
     var prevMonth = month -1;
     var day = dateNow.getDate();
     var year = dateNow.getFullYear();


     var dayPerMonth = ["31","28","31","30","31","30","31","31","30","31","30","31"]


     // days in previous month and next one , and day of week.
     var nextDate = new Date(nextMonth +' 1 ,'+year);
     var weekdays = nextDate.getDay();
     var numOfDays = dayPerMonth[month];
     var ul = document.getElementById('dates');
     var monthInt = month + 1;
     var currentMonth = document.getElementById('currentMonth');

     monthInt.toString().length === 1 ? currentMonth.innerHTML = "0" + monthInt : currentMonth.innerHTML = monthInt;

// add empty li
   while (weekdays > 0) {

     var li = document.createElement('li');
     ul.appendChild(li);

       weekdays--;

   }


 while (counter <= numOfDays) {

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = counter;
  ul.appendChild(li);


  counter++;

 }

}
```

It works fine but when I change month to August like this
 `var month = dateNow.getMonth() + 1;` 
 first date starts at Sunday. It should start at Wednesday.

I think this code is not working

```
while (weekdays > 0) {

         var li = document.createElement('li');
         ul.appendChild(li);

           weekdays--;

   }
```

In chrome it works and starts at Wednesday correctly. 
Anyone know why it's not working?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your date format. Chrome is being more generous in parsing the date you're giving it, which is a string that looks like `"7 1,2018"`. Chrome accepts that as a valid date, Safari doesn't. If you made sure you put slashes between the month, date, and year, like `"7/1/2018"` it would work better.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that in calculating nextMonth to put in your string you are assuming months in dates in js start with 1. But they start with 0. So your date now get month is giving you 6, not 7, and when you add 1 you are getting 7, not 8. Add 2 and you will get Wednesday like you want.
Specifically you need `var nextMonth = month + 2;`
I tested this in Firefox. I agree with the other posted answer about not loving the date format.
Also, you appear not to use prevMonth. You should remove it. Or if it you need for something, it should not have the -1.
Finally, you are going to want to revisit your index into the daysPerMonth array. If you want the number of days in next month, it is off.

Comment: It turns out I misunderstood the question. I will leave the answer in case It might be useful to some.

Answer (score 0):

As kshetline said, the problem was date format. 
Changed this code

`var nextDate = new Date(nextMonth +' 1 ,'+year);
 var weekdays = nextDate.getDay();`

to

```
var nextDate = new Date(year, month, 1);
var weekdays = nextDate.getDay();
```

then it worked fine!

Comment: I just tried this on Chrome and firefox in http://javascript.cs.lmu.edu/runner/ and put alert(nextDate) right after the NextDate= line you have here [I removed the window and html code] . Both show July 1. Does it do something different for you?

Comment: I think July 1 is correct because month is 6 which means July right?

Comment: Well, you said you were trying to set it tn next month, and it is July now. That would mean next month is August, or 7 in Javascript, which is the 8th month. And you seemed to be saying August 1 is not a Sunday, and so things were off. But I might have misunderstood your question.

Comment: I meant if date format is correct, add 1 to month then August will start with Wednesday. Sorry about that and thank you so much for your generous help!!